convex optimization with L1 and L2 regularization
Can we solve the problem with the form $$min_{x}||Ax - b||^2_2+\lambda||x||_1+\mu||x^2-y||^2_2$$ where y is a given vector.
This problem is a combination of least-squares regression with L1 and L2 regularization. The first term, $||Ax - b||^2_2$, represents the least squares problem, which aims to minimize the Euclidean distance between Ax and b. The second term, $\lambda||x||_1$, is the L1 regularization term, which encourages sparsity in the solution. The third term, $\mu||x^2 - c||_2^2$, is a variant of L2 regularization, where we are minimizing the Euclidean distance between the squared values of x and a given vector c.
Anyone know how to solve the problem? Thanks a lot.

What do you mean $x^2$; isn't $x$ a vector?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elastic_net_regularization

@Jürgen Sukumaran Probably should be $x$, not $x^2$.

@MarkL.Stone in fact they mean $x^2$ to be $x\odot x$ (Hadamard product, upon rereading the question) so it's quite distinct from elastic net I would say.

@JürgenSukumaran Yes that's correct. It just means the square of each element of the vector $x$

You could try Proximal Gradient method, which is classical for solving Lasso problems. However is not guaranteed to converge, and can even diverge, because your function is a fourth-degree polynomial. So it's a bit hard to work with.
In general, I think that Bregman proximal gradient is a more reliable way to go. See the paper First Order Methods beyond Convexity and Lipschitz Gradient
Continuity with Applications to Quadratic Inverse Problems by Bolte et. al. Treat $f(x) = ||Ax - b||^2_2+\mu||x^2-y||^2_2$ as the smooth part, and $g(x) = \lambda||x||_1$ as the non-smooth part.
This will require some analysis to devise the proper distance kernel $h$. I believe that a quartic kernel of the form
$$
h(x) = \frac{1}{4} \|x\|_2^4  + \frac{1}{2} \|x\|_2^2
$$
should work.  See Section 5.2 in the paper for derivation of the exact algorithm. Proposition 5.1 shows an exact formula for computing the update step of the algorithm so that you can implement it.

Thank you Alex, it seems to be a nice solution for the problem. I will give it a try.
